# Boxplot returns dashes instead of data

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I have dataframe similar to figure below in which I have two categories. I am trying to plot timeseries boxplot with **Values** based on two categories.

[image]

I am using the following code

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,6))

df2['ym-date'] = df2['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

sns.boxplot(x='ym-date', y='Values', hue='Category', data=df2, ax=ax)
plt.title('Boxplot of Values by A & B')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

And when used **hue**, it is showing me the following output
[image]

Whereas, when I do not use **hue**, I get the following output.

[image]

Any guidance please?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have enough data to draw box plots grouped by category.

It seems you only have two data points per date, one for each category. So when you exclude the `hue` parameter you get the full box plot (from two data points) and when you include the `hue` parameter each box plot only has one data point.

See this example:

```py
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
# Only keep cols we need
tips = tips[["day", "total_bill", "smoker"]]
```

If we make a subset of `tips` with only one data point for each category we get this:

```py
tmp = tips.groupby("day", as_index=False).head(1)
#      day  total_bill smoker
# 0    Sun       16.99     No
# 19   Sat       20.65     No
# 77  Thur       27.20     No
# 90   Fri       28.97    Yes

sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tmp)
```

[image: box plot with lines not box and whisker plots]

If we add two data points for each category:

```py
tmp = tips.groupby("day", as_index=False).head(2)
#      day  total_bill smoker
# 0    Sun       16.99     No
# 1    Sun       10.34     No
# 19   Sat       20.65     No
# 20   Sat       17.92     No
# 77  Thur       27.20     No
# 78  Thur       22.76     No
# 90   Fri       28.97    Yes
# 91   Fri       22.49     No

sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tmp)
```

[image: box plot with full boxes]

Now, if we add the `hue` parameter as `"smoker"` to the second example `Fri` has two options so those become single lines again:

```py
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tmp)
```

[image: box plots with mix of lines and bo]